# Esconder Teclado Android/Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Tenho um `EditText` que preciso que fique em foco,mas não abra o teclado em momento nenhum, pois ele receberá uma leitura de um Qrcode.

Tem como fazer isso?

Já tentei isso:

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_focus_qrcode_armazenagem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/caixa_txt"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Leia o endereço:"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_armazenagem" />
```

Comment: Tentou mudar o `android:focusable="true"` para `android:focusable="false"`?

Comment: Boa Tarde...isso pelo que vi apensas deixa em foco o texto,mas ainda se clicar abre o teclado

Answer (score 2):

Você pode desabilitar utilizando o showSoftInputOnFocus, ficando desta forma:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ........
    val txtFocusQrcodeArmazenagem = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.txt_focus_qrcode_armazenagem)
    txtFocusQrcodeArmazenagem.showSoftInputOnFocus = false
}
```

Comment: Mano!!! Top demais deu certo,agora vou deixar ele sempre foco